# What are the theoretical approaches to ambiguity?

Tags: asset-pricing, risk-aversion, uncertainty

I'm trying to understand the different approaches that economists took to investigate ambiguity. Two approaches particularly caught my eyes:

- the model by [Klibanoff, Marinacci and Mukerji (2009)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053108001749), and
- the model by Brenner and Izhakian ([2017](https://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeemateco/v_3a69_3ay_3a2017_3ai_3ac_3ap_3a91-103.htm), [2018](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X18301831)).

Could you explain to me where the crucial differences lie in these two approaches? If they are crucially different, is one model better suited for specific purposes?

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

Klibanoff, Marinacci and Mukerji (2009): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053108001749

Izhakian (2017):
https://econpapers.repec.org/article/eeemateco/v_3a69_3ay_3a2017_3ai_3ac_3ap_3a91-103.htm

Brenner and Izhakian (2018):
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X18301831

Comment: It would be nice to have full references or at least the titles.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - links have now been added to the question

Comment: Thank you for the links! Unfortunately, they tend to break over time. (We have experienced plenty of that on various sites of the Stack Exchange network.) Therefore, I still suggest adding full references.

Comment: Choquet Expected Utility is the standard approach for modelling ambiguity in decision theory. Its a bit strange as you replace probability measures with "capacities". Computationally  its similar to rank dependent utility if you are familar with that. A good resource on this topic is Peter Wakker's textbook "Prospect Theory for Risk and Ambiguity" https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/prospect-theory/971C92E9EADA3FAECE7AE94126E4CEB1

Comment: One could write several books about this topic; I would just start looking at some surveys such as [this one](http://www.econ2.jhu.edu/people/karni/ambiguity%20and%20nonexpected%20utility.pdf).